# Microsoft Graph scope "Domain.ReadWrite.All"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Why I can't set scope `Domain.ReadWrite.All` for url like:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=MY_APP_ID&response_type=code&state=12345&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44331%2F&scope=domain.readwrite.all

does not work.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=MY_APP_ID&response_type=code&state=12345&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44331%2F&scope=user.read

works.
It works also for `directory.readwrite.all` and any other, but does not work for `domain.readwrite.all`. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Domain.ReadWrite.All` is an application scope (client credential flow, aka app-only) and you are trying to have a user consent to that scope in a delegated auth flow.

To use `Domain.ReadWrite.All` you would need to do admin consent using the admin consent endpoint like this:

> GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent
>       ?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
>       &state=12345
>       &redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/permissions

Edited: updated to domain.readwrite.all

Comment: but `Directory.ReadWrite.All` works fine, I'm interested in `Domain.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: Apologies ... it should have been Domain.ReadWrite.All which is a application level scope. Edited the answer